# can't figure out why my mic wont work right

Tags: sound

if you guys can take a look at this video and give me any tips i have floureon bm 800 mic and a 48 v phantom power supply i have a feeling its my mic but i dont know  any tips will help a whole lot thanks so much

Comment: Did you read https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/44184/buzzing-hissing-issues yet? Even with phantom your still need a proper mic preamp. The video is too small to see anything btw.

Comment: Are you sure you weren't just inside of a tornado when you recorded the video?

Comment: lol yes would a new mic fix it and if so what mic could i get

Comment: @bentleycustoms97 how is it being plugged into your computer? And did you read the info from the link in the first comment?

Comment: i have everything expect the eternal sound card so it goes from the mic to power supply and then sright into my computer

Comment: straight lol sorry

Comment: Straight into your computer with USB or with a 3.5mm? What power supply?

Comment: 3.5mm and a 48v phantom powersupply the innogear one

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Buzzing, Hissing input level issues BM-700 BM-800 NW-800 Neewer/Floureon](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/44184/buzzing-hissing-input-level-issues-bm-700-bm-800-nw-800-neewer-floureon)

Answer (score 1):

My answer is probably better suited to a comment, but I don't have the reputation for that yet. So here goes...

Firstly, I'm not sure what part of the audio is not working *right* for you. I mean, it sounds awful. But what were you hoping for? (You **do** get what you pay for.)
Are you using any kind of audio interface? How is the mic connected to the computer? What is providing the phantom power?

You could be getting hiss from the mic itself, the cables, the power supply, or the pre amp. In your case, your computer is acting as pre amp, or rather the only amp. Any sound passed into the pre amp will be boosted. That includes all the noise in the signal not just your voice and the room sounds that it picks up. So any electronic noise in the signal chain will be boosted too.
That mic has XLR outputs which should cut down on noise (what you call static) in the cord that connects to the audio input on your computer.

It sounds like there may be some kind of automatic gain compensation turned on. That would explain why the background keeps getting louder when you are not speaking. Were you recording in a coffeehouse or something?
Also, the fact that the "static" or hiss (noise) gets turned up during these times you are not talking tells me that the noise is coming from one of the electrical components outside your computer.

Here's one more thing to check. Are you speaking into the correct part of the mic? If you are "off axis" you will get muted sound. That mic has a cardiod pick up pattern which means it will reject sounds from behind the capsule and favor sounds directly in front of the capsule. 
One problem I have seen with people unfamiliar with mics like the one you have is they will assume the mic pics up from the side or from the top. You can never be sure how the manufacturer has designed things. From the look of the pics on Amazon, this looks like a mic that pics up from the side. (Even though they have pictures with the pop filter protecting the top.)
If it **is** a side pic-up microphone and you are speaking into the wrong side, *if you are off axis*, you won't be happy with the sound. And the room sound will swamp the signal most of the time.

Comment: would a new mic fix it and if so which one thanks

Comment: For people new to microphones, I always recommend the Sure SM58. It does not require phantom power, it sounds great for the price, it is well made, and everyone from pros to amateurs uses them. They cost about $100, which may seem like a lot of money, but bang for your buck, the SM58 is the way to go.

Comment: You will still have the problem of getting sound **into** your computer so spend the extra $100 and get the Shure SM58-X2u Vocal Microphone with XLR-USB Adapter. **But** for people who just want to record themselves talking, go with Blue Microphones Yeti Studio USB Condenser Microphone. The USB bus on your computer will power the mic, so be sure your laptop is up to the job.

Answer (score 0):

The other answer states that an XLR cable should provide noise resistance.  But we are talking about a relabelled Neewer NW800 here.  That is essentially an unbalanced plugin-powered electret-capsule microphone with the delivered cable being XLR to unbalanced 3.5mm.

XLR connectors do not as such provide noise rejection: you need an actually balanced connection.  Now make no mistake: there *are* electret-biased condenser capsules powered with +48V phantom power and using either transformers or servo-balanced connections.  But those don't come with cables ending in a 3.5mm TRS plug.

It's unusual that this microphone will take 3V plugin power just as well (or rather just as awfully) as 48V phantom power.  But it's unlikely that its noise level will, even given 48V phantom power, be comparable to actual balanced circuitry *only* working at 48V.

However, that being said, your recording features *severe* dynamic compression without noise gating.  That kind of setup is only sensible in connection with unusually *quiet* microphones and the BM800 is an uncommonly *noisy* microphone.  So wherever your dynamic compression is coming from, be sure to switch it off.  You might want to add noise gating: if you choose to leave in the dynamic compression for whatever reason, your noise gating has to work on the compressed signal (usually called "side channel" then) while being triggered by the uncompressed signal.

I don't use Windows myself: I think I read somewhere that Windows 10 has changed some defaults regarding default compression of microphone signals.  Try figuring out where this can be switched on or off, either by searching the settings or searching the Internet for wisdom on that kind of thing.

Comment: would a new mic fix it and if so which one thanks