# Condensor mic with phantom power constantly buzzes

Tags: microphone, phantom, interference

I have a [AKG Pro Audio C214 Condenser Microphone](http://a.co/eOIiwvs) powered by a 48V phantom power device ([Neewer NW-100](http://a.co/frZaBQ6)). There is a very loud, low buzzing, the frequency of which would indicate that its AC interference.

When I turn off the phantom power device, the buzzing goes away and the mic is very clear for the short period of time before the capacitors drain. Would this indicate that the phantom power device is bad or poorly constructed? Is there anything else it could be?

Comment: Looks like an un-earthed, switch-mode PSU, so yes, quite likely. Can't say for certain & you can't earth it to test.

Comment: When you say “unearthed” is that similar to saying ungrounded? Is there a particular PSU you would recommend?

Comment: It's hard to tell from the photo, but it looks like a US or Japanese un-earthed plug [US calls that ground, which is technically wrong, mains earth & signal ground are not the same thing]. The only thing you could do to test is buy a new PSU with a real earth... then hope you have sockets with one, too. [I live in a country where un-earthed sockets are illegal]

Comment: If you're recording to a regular computer, I'd be tempted to follow this advice, even though I expect the AKG to be a considerably better mic, using USB with built-in phantom might solve your ground loop/lift issues - https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/44184/buzzing-hissing-issues/44185#44185

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'm looking at another PSU that has a DC power adapter, which seems like it may improve the issue since AC->DC conversion is occurring well away from the PSU itself.

Comment: That device needs 18v **AC** judging by the very fuzzy picture. Swapping to a DC PSU will have "unpredictable" results, from simply 'not working' to 'bursting into flames'. Don't try it.

Comment: To clarify, I'm looking at an entirely different PSU that takes 12V DC in.

Comment: Your device needs a PSU with 18v AC. It's that simple. You cannot just randomly swap it for another PSU.... unless you're mis-interpreting the term 'PSU'... power supply unit.

Comment: Phantom power is always DC. No matter which phantom power device is used, there will be an AC -> DC conversion somewhere.

Comment: Correct. However, unless you're going to throw away that Neewer phantom supply [which is still & always has been my prime recommendation] then it demands 18vAC input to generate it's poor & noisy phantom 48V DC. By the time you've matched a double conversion you could have simply bought a cheap USB mic preamp with built-in phantom that runs perfectly well off your computer's 5vDC with little to no discernible added noise. You can get a cheap & cheerful yet perfectly serviceable one for about $£€ 30 these days.

Answer (score 1):

To get from 18VAC to 48VDC you need to rectify and smooth *and* then use DC/DC conversion for doubling the voltage.  That gives you the inefficiency and weight of a transformer (I saw one review claiming to have it melt out of its casing) coupled with the noise problems of a DC/DC converter.

Now the NW-100 is more or less "designed" for use with Neewer "condenser" mics that are electret (and can also work at 5V).  Those have significantly higher signal levels, being suitable for computer mic inputs, than a good balanced microphone.  Being built to complement a high-gain low-quality mic, using it with a low-gain high-quality mic will showcase its qualities.

It also talks about its "robust plastic casing" which will not help with shielding.  Be sure not to place the phantom power box not anywhere near AC power including its own power brick.