# Laptop won't detect condenser microphone

Tags: microphone, audio-recording, sound, laptop

I have recently purchased a condenser microphone and a mixer which supports phantom power. I connected the microphone to the mixer and then connected the mixer with my laptop by using RCA. 
[image]
[image]

The green circle shows where I connected the microphone, red ones are the RCA connectors with a 6.3mm adapter and I also connected my headphones. 
Once I did all that, I can hear the sound coming from my laptop and also hear my voice when I talk into the microphone, but I am not able to record my voice on the laptop.

Comment: The red circled sockets are clearly labelled Line In. To send output you need to send from Main Out. You will not be able to monitor anything except the inputs using that equipment, it is not 2-way. You probably bought the wrong thing. See the answer at https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/44184/buzzing-hissing-issues/44185#44185 for some ideas.

Comment: @Tetsujin and what about the CD/TAPE ports, since there are Input and Output? Or the MAIN OUT

Comment: I'm not sure what you're actually asking about them. They allow you to run a tape machine in & out of the mixer, with optional routing to the headphones &/or Main.

Comment: So with my current setup I will not be able to record audio to my laptop?

Comment: Not until you connect the output of the mixer to the input of the computer.

Comment: I tried connecting using the MAIN OUT channels and still nothing. Which device would you recommend me to buy in order to make it work?

Comment: see my first link

Comment: After connecting the RCA cable to the Main outputs, did you open the Main Mix volume control?

Comment: Once I connected it, I was able to hear the audio coming from my laptop and my voice through the mic, but my laptop doesn't detect the microphone at all.

Comment: your laptop probably has a mono input, and you're inserting a stereo jack. that's another point of failure. What happens when you move the PAN control on channel 1 all the way to the left or right?

Comment: You provided no info about the way you are recording on your laptop so....Please do that so we can help!

Answer (score 1):

Not only are you using the input of the mixer, you are most probably plugging the cable into another output. Laptops generally don't have an input jack socket - the jack socket in most cases is a headphone output. Your connection path should be output of the mixer to input on the laptop, but I am fairly certain you won't find an input socket.

Your best solution is to get a cheap audio interface with a usb connection and plug the usb connector into the laptop, thus creating a separate audio interface. You can then connect this desk to your interface, or you can simply find a cheap desk that has a usb output interface.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be trying to OUTput from a pair of Line IN sockets!   Try feeding the computer from the Main Out sockets, or the Tape Out phonos.

It may be that the Mic In on your computer will auto-adjust to a line level signal.  Today's equipment is very forgiving in this way!    Try, anyway.