# Connecting Condenser Mic to an amplifier then to PC?

Tags: microphone, amplifier

I have BM800 condenser microphone which produces really low volume because it needs to be connected to a phantom power, I don't have a phantom power but I have an old Pioneer SA-600 amplifier.

[image]

[image]

How do I connect my condenser mic to this amplifier then to my PC for better recording?

Comment: It's not because the other post uses a phantom power which is much simplier.

Comment: The answer to the other post is how to make it work. Attempting to strap it to a 70's hi-fi amp will not.

Comment: I disagree. Condenser microphones are not home hifi.

Answer (score 0):

Consumer amplifiers cannot be used to amplify a microphone.

1. the signal level produced by a microphone is much lower than the level expected by the inputs on the amplifier. The difference is ~ 30-60 dB, which is a huge amount.
2. A condenser microphone [has some electronics built in](https://www.neumann.com/homestudio/en/what-is-a-condenser-microphone) which need to be powered. This power is supplied as 'phantom power' by the device you connect the microphone to.

What you need is a device that supplies phantom power. This can be a mic preamplifier or a mixer, but both of those output a line signal you have to get into the computer. 
In your case, a computer audio interface with a microphone input, as Tetsujin's [answer](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/44184/buzzing-hissing-input-level-issues-bm-700-bm-800-nw-800-neewer-floureon) dscribes, is the easiest way to get what you want.

Comment: Can I use a phantom power that supplies power only then use an external sound card? will that boos my condenser mic?

Comment: The 'external sound card' might as well be the device that supplies the phantom power. Please see the duplicate question, which answers all of this already.

Comment: Sound cards usually expect a line-level signal. To generate that, you need a microphone preamplifier (and you need one that can supply phantom power).