# Why is my input from my microphones so low?

Tags: microphone, recording, sound, music, youtube

I have 4 Behringer microphones (around £20) and a “SOUNDLAB 4 CHANNEL MONO MICROPHONE MIXER WITH EFFECTS“. I am attempting to start a podcast. When I record the audio, unless it is on full blast on all dials, I am unable to be heard. Even on full volume I am very quiet and drowned out by the white noise. The XLR cables I use are the default cables that came with the microphones. As the inputs are all 3.5mm I use a 3.5 to 1.35mm adapter that goes into my input line on my Mac. I record on Garage band. I also don’t have too much money to spend (only around £20-30) and I don’t have a lot of sound engineering expertise.

Comment: We need to know more about the mics. Best guess right now is they might need phantom power, or their impedance is badly matched to a 'headset' input. See https://sound.stackexchange.com/a/44185/9601 for a common issue with new users. Generally, 'pro' mics are not compatible with computer inputs. A mic preamp is required. i really cannnot tell what that mixer is meant to be, but I doubt it is meant to plug into a computer.

Comment: They are xm8500 ultra voice dynamic cardioid vocal microphones. Would I need one with 4 3.5mm inputs or would i connect my mixer into it?

Comment: Another thing to add is that my adapter that connects to my mac is a 3.5mm to 1.35mm and it jiggles about in the input port. The XLR cable leading into it also jiggles about.

Comment: Basically, you have too little input gain. The microphones output a low level signal (as dynamic mics do). The mixer seems to be quite a bit short on what gain it can produce (not even stated in the description). The mac expects a stronger signal than the mixer creates. Your solution would need to include more gain somehow. But even if you add the gain after your mixer, the mixer might be creating a lot of noise.

Comment: No-one seems to publish any spec on this mixer, but reading between the lines from the advertising blurb - "A micro mixer that can expand a single input on a music mixer to take up to 4 microphones." - the output is low impedance. It's expecting to go into a 'pro' mixer & is not matched to a computer input. You will probably need a dedicated mic>USB pre-amp. You can get one for £30 [just].

Comment: so I should ditch the mixer for a 4 input mic pre amp?

Comment: You'll end up buying 4 more cables, XLR-XLR, unbalancing, which will likely cost more than your mics. Buy a single input, buy a cable to get from the presumably unbalanced mixer out to the balanced interface in. Take it to a music shop & ask them what it needs, there's no spec published anywhere I can find to see precisely how it's wired.

Comment: okay thanks i’ll update you on it once i do this. Any recommendation on the preamp?