# White noise only when using a microphone connected to audio interface

Tags: microphone, noise, power, phantom

For starters, my setup is: **D. J. M - 800U** microphone and **Audient ID4** audio interface.

Originally the microphone came with a combined jack cable, so it essentially plugs into a USB interface and jack 3.5 simultaneously and it works fine. But I decided to buy an XLR cable to plug the mic into the audio interface I had and for whatever reason it records nothing except for white noise that I assume the mic itself produces. I tried working with and without the +48V, turned all the knobs, even those that couldn't be related to the issue, updated the software for the audio interface but nothing seems to help.

The audio interface could not be the issue since my monitors connected to it work fine, I also plug in my guitar into the D.I interface and it also works. The only thing I suspect might be at fault is the cable even though it's brand new, I literally got it today but I have no other XLR cables around to test this theory out. Any suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: Hard to find a link for… you mean something like this? https://www.thedailysale.shop/products/dw-mdj-m800u-condenser-mic-kit-for-studio-recording-podcasts-broadcast There's a [general QA on these mics](https://sound.stackexchange.com/q/44184/9601) - there are a myriad under various different names, usually found on amazon & ebay for very little money. I've never seen one with a USB cable - presumably to try pull a more generous 5v rather than the minimal votage some headset sockets can provide. As far as I'm aware, it should run fine on 48v phantom.

Comment: That's the mic, yeah. For whatever reason, it only works with the original combined jack-usb cable

Comment: I've never seen a model that sniffs USB power - I'd imagine that would make it more stable than 'laptop mic' power, but the one I have works perfectly well on phantom. Maybe they've changed the spec - they're never going to tell anyone, spec on these is … vague, at best.