# BM-800 Microphone doesn't work well with PC

Tags: microphone, audio, pc

I've read three or four other posts here about that microphone, althought none seems to have progressed much beyond "my microphone doesn't work."

The volume is very low on mine. I recognise that it's called a "condenser mic" and they usually require phantom power. Inside my Mic is a PCB which may well be a preamplifier, designed to be run from the 5V supply put out by my PC sound card. Certainly, this PCB is connected to all three XLR pins, at three different locations on the board, so clearly for three different functions.

However the XLR / 3.5mm jack cable suppled has pins 1 and 3 wired together in the XLR plug. In the 3.5mm jack plug, tip and ring are wired together. So, I don't see how this board can get power and also get the signal back down to the mic.

What's the board for? Have I been supplied the wrong cable?

Comment: They supply cables to try use PC mic power, but it's just not good enough practically. You need XLR>XLR & phantom. See https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/44184/buzzing-hissing-input-level-issues-bm-700-bm-800-nw-800-neewer-floureon/44185#44185

Comment: I'm not sure I've been understood. the wiring in the supplied cable means the board isn't even TRYING to draw power form the PC.

Comment: It's getting power, or it wouldn't work at all. It's just not getting enough, nor is your computer's mic jack sensitive enough for a low-impedance mic. They're designed to power cheap, high impedance electret condensers.

Comment: So, what's the board for, and, if it's a preamp which simply isn't getting enough power, why do folk recommend I buy a further additional preamp? How is one supposed to power it?

Comment: What's what 'board' for?? Did you read the linked QA which explains the whole thing. You have a low impedance mic you're trying to plug into a socket designed for a high impedance mic. You were sold a pup. Many, many others have fallen for this too. It will only work *properly* with a proper mic preamp which has phantom power… the same as any other 'pro' spec condenser.

Comment: Indeed I did read it. It tells me that the mic tries (unsuccessfully) to draw power from the PC. Perhaps you could steer me (or quote me) the passage explaining what the board is for? If it is, indeed, a pre-amp, then I imagine it could be powered externally, by battery without the need for an additional PSU.